# Wordpress creates shortlinks for each page and post

Tags: shortlink

When I checked my web site with SEO Powersuite, I see a shortlink created for each page and then 301 redirected to the actual URL. For example:

https://blokitap.com/?p=544     https://blokitap.com/iletisim/

I have no use for these shortlinks. Can I remove the shortlinks and 301 redirects?

Best Regards,

Comment: Do you mean not expose them anywhere? Or prevent them working in the first place?

Comment: Where exactly is SEO Powersuite finding them? i.e. do you need to remove the `Link: rel=shortlink` header, or something generated in your page header, or something else?

Comment: Hello remove them and 301's altogether. I think it's in the HTTP headers. Some suggested modifying functions.php but it didn't work. Then I found Remove WP version and shortlink plugin and it fixed it

Comment: these aren't shortlinks, they're a consequence of how WordPress URL routing works. Removing them would break ugly permalinks and have far and wide reaching consequences that lead to extreme weirdness and sometimes outright broken-ness. If you think this is a special feature that has been added that can be turned off or removed that is not the case. Hint: all pretty URLs are actually of the `index.php?var=value` type mapped underneath

Answer (score 0):

I used "Remove WP version and shortlink" plugin and it removed the shortlinks.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-wp-version-and-shortlink/

Comment: this plugin doesn't remove those URLs, or the 301 redirects, those are still there. The plugin just removes a meta tag in the header using a one line filter `remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_shortlink_wp_head');`. The shortlink is not an SEO penalty either

Comment: Hello, I'm checking with SEO Powersuite website auditor software. Shortlinks were shown as dynamic URLs and as warnings. Also there were 301 redirects as warnings. It doesn't say it's an error. But I would definitely not Google index them as /?p=123, I think that would not be a meaningful URL. After installing this plugin all the warning were gone. Powersuite is crawling as Googlebot, but of course there might be differences. I just enabled Search Console, I will see in a few days what Google indexes

Comment: if you visit them you'd be 301 redirected with a canonical tag which Google understands, they would not be indexed. Even some of the biggest sites in the world running WP have the shortlink tag without ill effects, e.g. https://techcrunch.com/2023/04/21/lyft-to-make-significant-cuts-across-ride-hailing-company/